# How to anti-symmetrize product of two tensors?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Say I have an anti-symmetric tensor $f_{ab}$ and two other tensors $M^{ij}$, $N^{kl}$ . Now consider the contraction $f_{ab}M^{ai}N^{bj}$, since we know $f_{ab}$ is anti-symmetric we know that for any tensor that is contracted with it, only it's anti-symmetric part will contribute to the contraction. Now my question is, wich of the following equations is true?

$$f_{ab}M^{ai}N^{bj} = f_{ab} \times  \frac{1}{2}(M^{ai}N^{bj} - M^{bi}N^{aj}) $$ or
$$f_{ab}M^{ai}N^{bj} = f_{ab} \times  \frac{1}{2}(M^{ai}N^{bj} - M^{bj}N^{ai})$$

A short explanation of why whichever is true holds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note$$f_{ab}M^{ai}N^{bj}=-f_{ba}M^{ai}N^{bj}=-f_{ab}M^{bi}N^{aj}.$$And averaging the first and last expressions,$$f_{ab}M^{ai}N^{bj}=f_{ab}\times\tfrac12(M^{ai}N^{bj}-M^{bi}N^{aj}),$$in agreement with your first attempt.